# Load ajax request inside main loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, canvas

Hello guys so I am working on the multiplayer coded with JavaScript and I would like to take data (x, y coordinates) from database and insert it in JavaScript and that it would be smooth animation, the problem with that is that ajax can't load data so fast (25 fps) any ideas how to insert data?

First the boatPosX and boatPosY are hardcoded in the beginning of the file as canvas.width/2 and canvas.height/2 let's say. Then there are click button events, which checks that when you go f.e to the right, boatPosX is incremented for 5px on canvas. And the x y coordinates are sent to database with ajax after each move. Now the other players has to see the opponent moving on canvas when it his turn to go and thus we need to get that x y data from database almost in real time inside render() main loop and draw graphics using x y data from database.

```
function render(viewport) {   
    context.save();
  //  if(Math.floor(boatPosX / 36) < 10) {
      context.translate(view.x, view.y);
    //}
    //if(Math.floor(boatPosX / 36) == mapArray.length)

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    var oldPosX = boatPosX;
    var oldPosY = boatPosY;

    var oldViewX = view.x;
    var oldViewY = view.y;

    for (let i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {

        if (mapArray[i][j] == 0 || 3) {
          this.sprite.draw(
            background,
            190,
            230,
            26,
            26,
            j * this.sprite.width,
            i * this.sprite.height,
            this.sprite.width,
            this.sprite.height
          );
        }
        if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
          this.sprite.draw(
            background,
            30,
            30,
            26,
            26,
            j * this.sprite.width,
            i * this.sprite.height,
            this.sprite.width,
            this.sprite.height
          );

        }
        if (mapArray[i][j] == 2) {
          this.sprite.draw(
            background,
            200,
            20,
            26,
            26,
            j * this.sprite.width,
            i * this.sprite.height,
            this.sprite.width,
            this.sprite.height
          );
        }
        if(Math.floor(boatPosX / 36) == mapArray[i].length - 2) {
          //console.log("finish");
          //boatPosX = Math.floor(mapArray[i].length * 36);
          moveCharacter = false;
          boatPosX = 580;
          endGame();
        }
      }
      //console.log(Math.floor(mapArray[i].length * 36));
    }
$.ajax({
  method: 'get',
  url : 'multiplayer/x.php',
  success : function(data){
    this.ship.drawimage(boat, data, boatPosY, 50, 50);
  }
})
    this.ship.drawimage(boat, boatPosX, boatPosY, 50, 50);
    this.ship2.drawimage(boat, boatPosX2, boatPosY2, 50, 50);
    if (view.x == -105) {
      view.x = -105;
    }
    //console.log(view.x)
    var lineHeight = 16 * 2.286;
    var textWidth = context.measureText(theArray[moveCount].question).width * 3;
    context.textAlign = 'left';
    context.textBaseline = 'top';
    context.font="14px Verdana";
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0 ,0.9)';
    context.fillRect(boatPosX + ship.width / 2, boatPosY - ship.height / 2, textWidth, lineHeight);
    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    if(moveCount < theArray.length) {
        context.fillText(theArray[moveCount].question, boatPosX + ship.width / 2, boatPosY - ship.height / 2);
    }
    context.fillText(theArray[moveCount].question, boatPosX + ship.width / 2, boatPosY - ship.height / 2);

    answerBtn1.innerHTML = theArray[moveCount].answer1;
    answerBtn2.innerHTML = theArray[moveCount].answer2;
    if(isPositionWall(boatPosX + 36, boatPosY)) {
      //boatPosX = oldPosY;
      console.log("collision");
    }

    if(foundGold(boatPosX + 36, boatPosY)) {
      goldAmount+= 1;
      gold.innerHTML = goldAmount;
    }

    checkMoveCounter();
    //console.log(mapArray[Math.floor(boatPosX / 36)]);
    //console.log(mapArray[Math.floor(boatPosX / 36)][Math.floor(boatPosX / 36)]);

    //RENDER FUNCTION END



    context.restore();

  };
```

Comment: Get all the data you need before you do the animation. Trying to fetch data using Ajax in real time for animation just won't work.

Comment: if it is not very big data then load it first and then use it in javascript if it is very big data then load it in chunks with ajax

Comment: As I understand, first the `boatPosX` and `boatPosY` are hardcoded in the beginning of the file as `canvas.width/2` and `canvas.height/2` let's say. Then there are click button events, which checks that when you go f.e to the right, `boatPosX` is incremented for 5px on canvas. And the `x` `y` coordinates are sent to database with ajax after each move. Now the other players has to see the opponent moving on canvas when it his turn to go and thus we need to get that `x` `y` data from database almost in real time inside render() main loop and draw graphics using `x` `y` data from database.

Comment: You could attempt integrating your DB infrastructure with `Firebase` framework since it has `real-time DB communication` functionality.

Reading material: [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database)